# How to pass ngx-transalate json file to component

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have following code

```
<app-select

                  ngDefaultControl
                  [label]= "Caller"
                  [items]="users"
                  [multiple]="false"
                  [required]="true"
                  (selectedValueChanges)="selectCallReceviedByChanges($event)"
                  >
                ></app-select>
```

In the label I want to pass ngx-translate json key. (CALL.CALLER.TITLE).

```
[label]= {{ 'CALL.CALLER.TITLE' | translate }}
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Simple

```
 [label]="'CALL.CALLER.TITLE' | translate"
```

Comment: Alternatively you can still do `label="{{ 'CALL.CALLER.TITLE' | translate }}"`